measuring peak memory usage of a very fast program on windows
I've got a program that runs in a very short time (less than a second), on windows, in a powershell terminal.
How can I measure "easily" it's peak memory usage (I cannot see it in the resources monitor)?
NB: I'd like, also, to compare the behavior, with respect to memory usage, of the same code compiled with different compiles (cl, clang and gcc), all on windows.
Ideally I'd need an equivalent of linux command:
/usr/bin/time -v ./test

which returns Maximum resident set size (kbytes)

My attempt:
test.ps1
# Set the path to my application
$applicationPath = ".\test.exe"

# Set a delay (in seconds)
$delayInSeconds = 10

# Wait for the specified delay
Start-Sleep -Seconds $delayInSeconds

# Start the application
Start-Process -FilePath $applicationPath -PassThru

# Wait for the specified delay
Start-Sleep -Seconds $delayInSeconds

It wraps the call of the fast test.exe inside a powershell script that start by waiting, giving me time to set monitoring and wait again to set a measure point after test.exe execution.
bench.ps1
# Get the process ID
Write-Host "Launch bench"
$processId = Start-Process -FilePath "powershell.exe" -ArgumentList "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File .\test.ps1" -PassThru
$id = $processId.id
Write-Host "Process ID: $id"

# Set the desired delay (in seconds)
$delayInSeconds = 15

# Wait for the specified delay
Start-Sleep -Seconds $delayInSeconds

# Measure peak memory usage (working set) for the process
$peakMemoryUsage = (Get-Process -Id $id).PeakWorkingSet64 / 1MB

# Display the process ID and peak memory usage
Write-Host "Process ID: $processId"
Write-Host "Peak Memory Usage: ${peakMemoryUsage} MB"

I'm trying here to launch test.ps1 in a child process of which I get the Id to feed it to monitoring commands.
The child process is actually launched and seems to run fine but I always measure the same value even when varying the amount of allocations in test.exe.
For instance I added:
std::vector<std::string> v(10000000,"Very long string to allocate at least something");
std::cout << v.back() << '\n';

and compiled without optimization. But the output memory remains the same, whatever the size of the vector.
My guess is that Start-Process -FilePath $applicationPath -PassThru actually launch another process outside the calling one, thus I don't measure it.

Another idea would be to add a pause inside test.exe and launch it directly, not inside a wrapper. It may work but I would still appreciate a solution that does not need "tooling" inside the exe (because it won't always be possible).

Why is bench.ps1 spawning test.ps1 in a separate process? Why not just launch the target program with Start-Process and read the peak ws directly off the resulting process object?

@MathiasR.Jessen the target process is very short. I need a way to extend it's lifetime in order to actually measure something. My first try was to wrap it into another process that adds a wait before and after the actual computation in order to give time to launch the measure command and run it after the end of the actual computation but before the monitored process finishes. (the "before" wait is perhaps useless in fact)

I see the problem - unfortunately though, your "solution" gives you the peak memory of the powershell.exe process launching the target process - not the target process itself

@MathiasR.Jessen Indeed, It was my guess. So far I could make the "Another idea" work but it requires to add a sleep inside the exe. I'd prefer a solution without that but I'm getting unsure that it's possible

Does "maximum resident set" mean the same thing as "peak working set"?  I maintain that working set size is a poor metric for measuring a program's memory demands, especially when trying to compare programs side by side.  Certainly, a program's memory needs is a major driver of its working set size, but there are many other factors, and, ultimately, the OS controls the working set size.  All those other factors are virtually impossible to control.  I prefer commit size which, unless the program attempts to adjust its usage in response to outside factors, is more consistent.
